# Powershell script to download either zip or csv

Tags: powershell, ssis

I use ssis to run a powershell script to download a file that used to be csv but recently became large enough to be zipped. I updated the powershell script to look for a zip file and added a task to the package to unzip the file so it can be loaded into a sql database. Well, then it came through as a csv again. I need a solution to choose either the zip file or the csv file. Not sure if this should be a task in ssis or updated powershell.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: I have an ssis package that runs a powershell script to download the file, which looks like this https://blog.exsilio.com/all/how-to-use-powershell-or-ssis-to-download-a-sharepoint-file/
and that is followed by a task that unzips the file, then a task to load it to the db

Comment: That doesn't help clarify your question. Can you be more specific about what you are doing, what isn't working, and _how_ it isn't working? (Remember, participants reading your question from this website cannot access your system and cannot see your screen.)

Comment: Why not have a path for both options? the zip goes through an unzip process and the csv goes straight to the load

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a PS task to download the files (either zip/csv) then SSIS foreach container to iterate over the files you just downloaded. Doing this you will assign the individual file to a user variable. Inside your container if the file is zip, (use a variable set via an expression to determine if it is zip or not) run a task that will run PS to unzip and then a expression task to update the variable that holds the file path to be the newly unzipped csv path. Then run your data flow task to import the csv.

If the file is a csv to begin with, then just run the DFT.

Either way the data flow task is the same, take csv and load it. I have found I like to keep my PS in SSIS packages very purpose driven. I have a tendency to build my logic in PS because it is easier, but then my package becomes harder to debug because an issue in my PS script will fail the SSIS package and SSIS tells me nothing usefull about what in the script failed. (unless you are handling redirecting of stdout and stderr from your PS, or doing some other logging) 
Best to keep the powershell as simple as needed for each task you need to do.